# Plugin to Merge Lead On Creation

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

## Platform

Dynamics CRM 2016 online
C#, plugin

A lead is created, and a plugin fires on create , which tries to find any Lead with the same email and merges this new Lead into the old one.
So the plugin fires on creation of Lead B (Post operation)

Finds a Lead with the same email(assume Lead A), it merges Lead B into Lead A.

## Problem

Lead B is never saved, no error is thrown but the save indicator keeps rotating.
And nothing else happens, i.e. no merging etc

## Debugging

Changed the logic a bit to run the plugin on Update (Create step was disabled).
It worked perfectly, exactly same code.

## Question

Is this step i.e. merging not possible from inside a Create plugin of the record being merged.

## Code

```
        MergeRequest merge = new MergeRequest();
        merge.SubordinateId = targetEntity.Id;
        merge.Target = new EntityReference(primaryLead.LogicalName, primaryLead.Id);
        merge.PerformParentingChecks = false;
        merge.UpdateContent = updateContent;
        MergeResponse merged = (MergeResponse)svc.Execute(merge);
```

targetentity is the record for which the plugin is fired and primary lead is  the result of a fetch query
updateContent is some data to be copied into the merged lead.

Answer (score 0):

Change plugin to Async and that should work fine.